# SQL resulting table satisfies two conditions

Tags: sql

I hope I can explain this well enough.

Say I have this table:

```
Owner
+--------+--------+
| Name   | Type   |
+--------+--------+
| Bob    | Cat    |
| Bob    | Dog    |
| Bob    | Cow    |
| Tim    | Dog    | 
| Tim    | Cat    |
| Ted    | Cat    | 
| Joe    | Dog    |
| Joe    | Cat    |
| Joe    | Sheep  |
+--------+--------+
```

I am trying to find everyone who has all the animals tim has (so a cat and a dog). This means Joe and Bob would satisfy this, but not Ted as he only has one type of animal Tim has

How would I go about getting this result?

So I have a table with all the types tim owns:

```
SELECT Type FROM Owner WHERE Name= 'Tim';
```

How do I get it so that only those who have both Types tim has get selected from the list of owners?

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name
from owner
where type in (select distinct type from owner where name = 'tim')
group by name
having count(distinct type) = (select count(distinct type) from owner where name = 'tim')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get all the persons who have more animals than Tim `has` then you can do it like

```
select Name from owners
group by Name
having count(distinct [Type]) > (select count(distinct type) from owners
where Name='tim')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as a `join` and `group by` problem.  Join Tim's records to all the other owners, but on the `type` field.  Then do an aggregation and keep only the records where all the `type`s match:

```
select o.name
from owner otim left join
     owner o
     on o.type = tim.type and o.name <> 'Tim' and otim.name = 'Tim'
group by o.name
having min(case when o.type is null then 0 else 1 end) = 0;
```

Note that this works even when duplicate `type` values are allowed in the table.